# Which is better for an adjustable stable reference voltage output?

Tags: voltage, zener, reference

I have two methods of achieving this and am trying to decide which one will be a better option for a stable output. The supply voltage is a linear regulator output, so it is pretty much constant.

Option 1: Using op-amp with voltage divider using 1v Zener diode (TZMC1V0-GS08)
[image]

Option 2: Using op-amp with voltage divider circuit
[image: Using op-amp with voltage divider circuit]

The adjustable range should be at max +/-2V, at this voltage having an accuracy of 0.01% is much preferred
The output in both cases will be connected to one of [OPA875](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa875.pdf) inputs which has an internal Av=+2. I guess in this case, the output current demands are negligible

Let me know if you have any questions

thanks

Comment: another isse in the top one, is R10,R11 = 50ohm look like they will reduce range of adjustment too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Update below.

Nowhere in your post do you say what your accuracy and stability requirements are, or anything about power budget, cost budget, output current, noise bandwidth, etc.; so all of this is guesswork.

The first circuit will not work; the opamp output shorted (through R12 and R13) to what I think is a GND symbol drawn incorrectly.  Also, low voltage zener diodes are not nearly as stable as 6.2 V - 6.8 V parts.  But no zener diode can compete with a high-accuracy and high-stability reference IC from National Semi, Analog Devices, Linear Tech, or Maxim.  Yes, I know some of those companies have been bought and sold, but the old names are better.

In terms of accuracy and stability, the second circuit is much worse.  It depends on the performance of two different voltage regulators, neither of which is designed for reference duty, plus the thermal performance of three resistors.  Compared to an old, cheap LM4040, its output will wander around every time the door opens or someone walks by.

I would start with the first circuit, go with only one reference diode, and (if you really need a bipolar output voltage range) a different opamp circuit with gain that ranges from +1 to -1 with a single pot.

UPDATE

Here is a schematic from an old issue of Electronic Design for an opamp circuit that goes from positive to negative gain with a single pot adjustment.  For your application, ignore the A2 circuit

[image]

The gain of the A1 stage goes from +0.5 to -0.5.  With a 4.096 V reference IC, the output will swing from +2 V to - 2 V.  Note that the source impedance at V1 must be zero ohms, or very low relative to the other resistor values.  And, of course, use something other than a 741.

You still have not told us the output voltage range you need, so, again, this is mere speculation.

Comment: Thanks for your response, R12 and R13 are there only as place holders, they are not actually being used. In other words with this op-amp they are DNI. Sorry for not being clear there. Also these circuits are old ones that I am reviewing while upgrading the electronics in our systems. We do need bi-polar reference output.

Comment: Updated the answer with a schematic.

Comment: The ideal range we need is +/-1V, but +/-2V would work too. Please refer to my original post as i updated with  more details.

Comment: Also, thanks for the reference schematic, will give it a try

Comment: Since the output is adjustable with a pot, the accuracy of the initial value of the reference is almost irrelevant.  Way more important are temperature coefficient and long-term drift.  The LM4040 (and just about any decent line of reference ICs) is available in 2.048 V and 2.500 V to meet your range requirement.  Other than that, shop around for stability; there are a ton of parts to choose from.  Here are some thoughts from TI.  https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva510b/snva510b.pdf  National used to make the LM399, a single-chip oven-stabilized voltage reference.  Excellent.

Comment: Great, thanks again. Upon shopping around, I came across LTC6655 with tolerance of +/-0.005% and TC or 5ppm/C, that lowest for 1.25V output at 5mA. For 2.048V, the best I came across is ADR440 with  +/-0.05% tolerance and 3ppm/C at 10mA output. I can try both, but wondering which one would you prefer?

Comment: One quick question, can the output of stage A2 be used as an input for multiple A1 stages, lets say if I want to add 8 different adjustable outputs? The input of A1 stage will be at high impedance (OPA227), so it shouldn't be demanding more current on its input. LTC6655 at 1.25V output has max of 5mA output while ADR440 has 10mA at 2.048V output. Thanks again for your suggestions

Comment: The A1 stage input impedance is set by the component values, not by the device.  With the components in the schematic, it is 3.3K.  Divided by 8, the load on the reference is 416 ohms.

Comment: Just tested A1 stage using unity gain stable OP27 op-amp and 2.048V at V1, I am getting a range of -1.02 to 0.998 with current consumption of 3 to 4mA max. I adjusted the output to 0.26mV and kept monitoring its stability over time, after about 10min, it slowly crept to -0.21mV and stayed there. The input at V1 is from a linear regulated power supply set at 2.048 CV. This is pretty good. Depending on how many independent adjustments I need, can I increase A1's input resistors values to change the load on the reference?

Comment: The ratios of the four resistances must be maintained.  Note - as R1 increases, input bias current error increases.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, they're both pretty awful compared to what can be achieved with the cheapest of components.

I suggest using 2x TL431 (cheapest) or LM4040 (better-est) and a similar circuit to the top one.

The 1V zener has a tempco of ~`0.25%/K which is -2500ppm/K, so it makes a better temperature sensor than a reference. The LM4040 and TL431 are 10 or 20 times better and much more common parts.

You should also try to reduce the influence of the pot element resistance by shunting it with a resistor or connecting it to 'stiff' voltage sources and sorting out the voltage range with your op-amp. Your resistor values don't make a lot of sense, so I am assuming they are placeholders.

Using the supply voltages as a reference (bottom schematic) is possible, but usually undesirable.

You also need to decide whether you want to bypass to ground or to the minus supply. Usually (almost always) ground is the correct choice but the bottom schematic does not show that.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, as I was stating above, these are old schematics that I am taking over to rebuild the electronics that these are being used in. Will look into your suggestions